# Accessibility Service - performGlobalAction() is not working?

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I am creating an Android [Accessibility](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html) Service which calls [performGlobalAction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#performGlobalAction%28int%29)

```
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityWindowInfo;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;
    
public class RootChecker extends AccessibilityService {


    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
    }


    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
    }

    public void BackKey() {
        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
}
}
```

i am calling it from another class named TouchViewManager.

```
RootChecker rc = new RootChecker();


public void PressBack(){
      rc.BackKey();
}
```

My service class named TouchWindowService

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;


public class TouchWindowService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "TouchWindowService";
    private TouchViewManager touchViewManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
     touchViewManager = TouchViewManager.getInstance();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

i followed the Guide and add necessary service in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".TouchWindowService"/>

        <service android:name=".RootChecker"
                 android:label="@string/accessibility_service_label"
                 android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                    android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />

        </service>
```

accessibilty_service_config code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                       android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
                       android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
                       android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
                       android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
                       android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
        />
```

**What i have Tried**
My Accessibility Service is Enabled for my app .
Also, i use `Thread.sleep(1000);` before `performGlobalAction();` But it not working for me.

**Problem**
AccessibilityService is not Working for me.

**Question**
when i click on button nothing Happened.
Is there anything i am missing like Imports.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use BroadcastReceivers to communicate with RootChecker or create a singleton in the RootChecker to access its methods

```
private static RootChecker instance;

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    instance = this;
}

public static RootChecker getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
```

And use that to access your AccessibilityService

```
RootChecker.getInstance().BackKey();
```

Comment: Can I have your email address for talking about accessibility service. My email address is thungerwing@gmail.com . Give me a mail at this email. Please mail me